# Display custom-post type based on the Title matching the current selected value

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, jquery, ajax, input

Ok quite a complex thing I'm trying to do here, and I'm a bit unsure how I will do it with wordpress, but I'm hoping some genius out there can help.

I'm basically creating some comparison functionality, and I currently have two select boxes on the page. These select boxes will display the list of all posts within the custom post-type **'countries'** inside them, and when the user selects one of the options from the list, I will use ajax to display the content of that particular post below.

I currently have a non-wordpress version of what I am trying to do, and here's the code.

**HTML**

```
<select id="compare-one">
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#compare-one').change(function(e){
$('#compare-one-container').empty();
$(this).find(':selected').each(function(i,e){
    $.get("callbacks.php",
      // used to prevent caching in IE
      { nbRandom: Math.random() },
      function(data){
        $("#compare-one-container").html(data);
     });  
});
```

});

**callbacks.php**

```
<?php $test = "Home" ?>
```

So as you can see, I have no implemented this into Wordpress just yet - simply because I'm unsure of the right way to do so!

**I think my main question is how to replace this current php code with something that checks to see if the *current selected value* is equal to *the page title*, and if so *echo the information (content, custom fields etc) from that particular page title* it matches.**

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really get what your main issue.. are you try to comparing two post types and display it in a page template? or are you try to comparing the current page with the selected post types?

try this create a page template

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Compare
 */
?>

<?php
get_header();   
?>


        <form id="customsearch" action="" method="post">
            <select name="compare-one" id="compare-one">
                <option value="130">1</option>
                <option value="102">2</option>
            </select>

            <select name="compare-two" id="compare-two">
                <option value="130">1</option>
                <option value="102">2</option>
            </select>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#compare-one').change(function() {
                var compareone_value = $('#compare-one').val();
                var data = {
                    'action':'callback_function',
                    'compare-one':compareone_value, 
                };
                $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    $('#compare-one-container').html(response); 
                });
            });

            $('#compare-two').change(function() {
                var comparetwo_value = $('#compare-two').val();
                var data = {
                    'action':'callback_function',
                    'compare-two':comparetwo_value, 
                };
                $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    $('#compare-two-container').html(response); 
                });
            });

        });
</script>              
<div id="compare-container">
    <div id="compare-one-container">

    </div>

    <div id="compare-two-container">

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

next add a callback function to your functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_callback_function', 'callback_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_callback_function', 'callback_function'); // for not logged in user
function callback_function() {
if (isset($_POST['compare-one']) || isset($_POST['compare-two'])) {
            $arr_id = array($_POST['compare-one'],$_POST['compare-two']);
            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query = null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();

            $wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'listing', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'post__in' => $arr_id));
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                $beds = $custom['_beds'][0];
                $baths = $custom['_baths'][0];
                apply_filters('the_title', the_title());
                apply_filters('the_content', the_content());
            endwhile;
            $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
            rewind_posts();

    }
    die();
}
?>
```

and don't forget to localize WordPress ajax script to use in front page

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting
```

Comment: for the select option I use my own post type and post id so it's 130 and 105 :D and the post type is listing

Comment: perfect! All I added was some code to the select boxes so that I dynamically grab all posts and their ids:

`<?php $city = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'city', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 )); ?>
                                <?php while ($city->have_posts() ) : $city->the_post(); ?>
                                    <option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Nice to see it work well.. please vote for the answer if it's really helpful

Comment: regarding your code, I've adjusted it slightly, but for some reason I just cannot seem to echo the value of a custom-field I created using Magic fields:

Between the 'while' statement I included:

`$timezoneshow = get('timezone');
echo $timezoneshow;`

But for some reason it breaks the whole thing. I also wondered whether it's better to move the display parts to the actual template file (ie. echo the title and content in the template file rather than the functions.php). I'm not an expert with PHP so some advise would be great

Comment: is the timezone your custom field related to the post or it's another function?

Comment: if you want more powerful way using Ajax to loop your content, I found a good tutorial here [link] (http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/)

Comment: the timezone custom field simply displays a string, so 'GMT+1', 'GMT-12', 'GMT' etc. Is there a way we could break up your code so that I can actually use it in the template page file rather than echoing the content in the functions.php, I think this might solve things but I'm not very sure how to do it!

Comment: I don't know what is the best method but maybe you can duplicate the function and let the function returned the difference value you need then use multiple response. but with that method it will be a long request I would suggest you to in style the div in the functions instead of doing multiple request

Comment: $('#compare-one').change(function() {
    var compareone_value = $('#compare-one').val();
    var data = {
     'action':'callback_function',
     'compare-one':compareone_value, 
     
    };
    var data2 = {
     'action':'callback_function2',
     'compare-one':compareone_value, 
    };
    
    $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function(data1) {
     $('#compare-one-container .content').html(data1);
    });
        
    $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, data2, function(data2) {
     $('#compare-one-container .title').html(data2);
    });
    
   }); here is what I try

Comment: it's a bad method I think, if you want more advance method you need to make the request return as an XML, and that's beyond my knowledge

Comment: Hi @nackle - not sure what your last chunk of jquery was supposed to be doing? 

We're almost there, because everything is working great but it's very important that I am able to include this custom field in your php code you gave me earlier. Would be great if anybody has a solution?

Comment: thanks a lot for you help. Really appreciate it. I solved the issue by simply using `get_meta()` in your php code rather than using Magic Field's own syntax of `get()`

Comment: nice to see everything goes well.. have fun with WordPress